# docker-compose.yml Syntax for Named Volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

What is the `docker-compose.yml` syntax for specifying the host path of a named volume?

### docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
  myvolume:  # how do I specify path here?
  othervolume:

services: # etc...
```

I've checked the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/), but I can't find it. Honestly, I don't know how anyone uses this stuff.

Answer (score 33):

The common scenario with compose volumes is to use the default named volume which maps to the local volume driver and places volumes in /var/lib/docker/volumes. Not what you're looking for, but this is the easy option for many:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  myvolume:
  othervolume:    
services:
  myservice:
    volumes:
      - myvolume:/volume/path
```

The common method to map a host volume is to specify the path directly, no name needed on the volume. Again, not what you're asking for, but it's very easy to implement. This is a bind mount under the covers:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    volumes:
      - ./path:/volume/path
```

If you want a named volume and host volume together, what you're looking for is a named volume configured to use a bind mount. This has the downside of failing if the directory does not preexist, but has the upside that docker can init an empty directory to the contents of the image.

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  myvolume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /host/path/to/volume
services:
  myservice:
    volumes:
      - myvolume:/container/volume/path
```

Note, the downside of bind mounts is that it places files that are managed by containers, with the uid/gid from the container, inside a path likely used by other users on the host, often with a different uid/gid on the host. The result is permission issues either on the host or inside the container. You need to align uid/gid's between the two to avoid this.

Comment: How can you tell what the container uid/gid's are?

Comment: @Thor84no Linux commands like `id` will work the same inside a container as on the host.

Comment: yeah, but I can't get the container to stay up for long enough to try that due to "permission denied" errors. :(

Comment: @Thor84no you can start your container with a different command, e.g. `tail -f /dev/null`

Comment: @zhkzyth any command that doesn't immediately error out will work to keep the container running, but for release, you want your application running in the foreground.

Comment: @BMitch Thanks for explanation. Can you tell me is it also possible to use named-volume reference in more deeper path like below or there is an alternative way to achieve it?

myservice:
 volumes:
    - named-volume/data:/data
    - named-volume/logs:/logs
    ....

Answer (score 0):

In the same reference docs you can check complete expanded version of sample docker-compose.yml

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#compose-file-structure-and-examples

See db section for named volume mounting.

```
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. How do I set the path of a named volume at the highest scope?

Comment: you do not have to specify path of named volume. You can create a named volume using `docker volume create myvol` and then use this named volume while mounting.